# How to resolve and initiate object using autofac and json

Tags: c#, json.net, autofac

I have registered services like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<NoticeEmail>().Keyed<INoticeChannel>(ChannelType.Email);
builder.RegisterType<NoticePushover>().Keyed<INoticeChannel>(ChannelType.Pushover);
```

and I am resolving them as follows:

```
public INoticeChannel Resolve(ChannelType type, string message)
    {
        var r = _context.ResolveKeyed<INoticeChannel>(type);

        Type myType = Type.GetType(r.GetType().Name);

        var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, myType);

        return r;
    }
```

Resolving is working great but I also would like to initiate the object with json data from `message` and return the specific object. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why are you calling `Type.GetType(r.GetType().Name)` instead of simply using `r.GetType()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code:

```
var r = _context.ResolveKeyed<INoticeChannel>(type);

Type myType = Type.GetType(channel.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);

var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(message, myType);
```